# error in building jar file in netbeans

Tags: java, jar

Not copying library C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gc , it's a directory. Why this error occurs while building a jar file. Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Can you show the exact command you are using to run the jar from the command prompt please?

Comment: Write here your promt command pls.

Comment: java -jar gc.jar    ... gc is my project name

Comment: Is your `CLASSPATH` set-up properly or do you use specify it correctly in command line?

Comment: You can also use `-classpath` or `-cp` in your command line to set `classpath` just for this invocation.

Comment: Just to double-check: `gc.jar` is located in one of the directories (folders) included in your `classpath`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a manifest?

There's normally a default manifest:   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html

You have to set an entry point:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Basically, create a META-INF\Manifest.MF file.  Then, and add "Main-class:<your main class> e.g. com.example.blahclass" (if you're not using packages, then don't keep the com.example part)

Comment: Not copying library C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gc , it's a directory. this is the error i m getting while building a jar file.. help me